# How can we merge 2 branches in SVN repository (checkout is done for both in android studio) in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, svn

I have a project code in svn's trunk folder and some changes in the same has been done in branch. I would like to merge both in another branch. How can we do this in android studio? Which version of SVN should I use in android studio to support the same?